# Do hard tires reduce life of suspension in the long run?

Tags: tires, suspension

I recently bought a new family sedan which comes with the hard stock tires. Now I am worried whether they could reduce the life of suspension parts in near future. Should I change the stock tires to some good quality soft ones?

Comment: What do you mean by "hard"? Hard material (rubber compound)? Stiff sidewall? High pressure? What makes the stock tires harder than a soft tire?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 it's hard rubber compound I guess because the ride feels bumpy with the recommended tire pressure.

Comment: I've never heard of "hard" vs. "soft" tires.  It might help if you updated your question with the specific brand and model of tires you have and are considering.

Answer (score 1):

If the ride is hard it's not because of the tire compound, changing to a different brand isn't going to improve things. Tire compounds effect your grip on the road, not your ride. If your ride is hard it may be because:

- You have run flat tires: run flat tires are stronger as they have to provide rigidity after a loss of pressure, so they have a harder ride. You could change to regular tires, but you'd have to change the rims in most cases
- Over-inflated tires: check to make sure you haven't put too much air in
- Worn suspension: old shocks and bushings can give a hard ride, if it's a used car you may want to get that checked (The post says new car so I'm adding this for completeness if others have the same issue)
- The car is designed for a harder ride: Different makes go for different rides as harder is 'sportier', with a BMW sedan you'll feel every pebble in the road whereas a Lincoln Continental will have much more 'float'

As for damage, if a car is designed for a harder ride then the components will stand up to it.

Comment: Another cause of ride hardness (compared to a previous vehicle) is different tires with a lower aspect ratio. When the wheel rim and the ground are closer together, there's less rubber and air to absorb impacts.